# Glue secret manager integration: secretId is not provided

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-spark, aws-glue-connection, aws-glue3.0

I am running the glue pyspark script from my local machine using the GlueETL library.

When creating a dataframe from glue catalog,

```
dyf_user_book_reading_stat = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="xxx-db",
    table_name="xxx_table"
)
```

I'm getting this error

> GlueContext: Glue secret manager integration: secretId is not
> provided.

What is the secretId that it is asking for and how to provide it?